# How to prevent two processess from fighting for a common cache?

Tags: multithreading, caching, mpi, cpu-cache

I was asked this question on an exam. We have two CPUs, or two cores in the same CPU, that share a common cache (for example, L3). On each CPU there is an MPI process (or a thread of one common process). How can we assure that these two processes don't interfere, meaning that they don't push each others entries out or use a half of the cache each or something similar. The goal is to improve the speed of memory access here.

The OS is some sort of Unix, if that is important.

Comment: What's wrong with using half of the cache each? sounds like a desired balance to avoid interference. Just align them to different parts of the cache (assuming they can fit)

Comment: @Leeor oh, I didn't think it is possible to setup this. So, the question is - how to do that? :) I mean, I'm talking about a hardware CPU cache here - like L2 or L3. Is it possible to control alignment of processes in it?

Comment: Was this on a written exam? Because this looks much more like an interview question than an exam question. It's the kind of question you ask without expecting an answer -- you expect to learn how the person reasons by what questions they ask you and by how they reason about the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the exam was interview-like, exactly. But the professor who interviewed me (so to say) insisted there is a solution to this problem. I myself couldn't come up with anything better than locking one of the processes while the other one is working, but this probably shouldn't lead to any performance improvements :) And I didn't get his suggested answer after the exam as he was probably going to ask it to those going after me.

Comment: You clearly have three choices: 1) Run the tasks one at a time. 2) Split the cache in a fixed way. 3) Let them fight over the cache.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ok, and how can I split it actually? Is there some syscall for that, or should that be done in the logic of memory access somehow?

Comment: @InnotKauker That goes way beyond the question which doesn't give us the kind of details necessary to give that kind of answer. That's not the kind of answer that could be appropriate to such a generic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems that a "textbook answer" is expected, so I would suggest partitioning the cache between the processes. This way you guarantee that they don't compete over the same cache sets and thrash each other. This is assuming you don't want to actually share anything between the 2 processes, in which case this approach would fail (although a possible fix would be to split the cache space in 3 - one range for each process, and one for shared data).

Since you're probably not expected to redesign the cache and provide HW partitioning scheme (unless the question comes in the scope of computer architecture course), the simplest way to achieve this is simply by inspecting the cache size and associativity, figuring our the number of sets, and aligning the data sets of each process/thread to a different part.

For example, if your shared cache is 2MB big, and has 16 ways and 64B lines, you would have 2k sets. In such case, each process would want to align its physical addresses (assuming the cache is physically mapped) to a different half 1k sets, or a different 0x10000 out of each 0x20000. In other words, P0 would be free to use any physical address with bit 16 equals 0 , and P1 would use the addresses with bit 16 equals 1.

Note, that since that exceeds the size of a basic 4k page (alignment of 0x1000), you would either need to hack your OS to assign your pages to the appropriate physical addresses for each process, or simply use larger pages (2M would be enough).
Also note that by keeping a contiguous 0x10000 per allocation, we still enjoy spatial locality and efficient hardware prefetching (otherwise you could simply pick any other split, even even/odd sets by using bit 6, but that would leave your data fractured.

Last issue is for data sets larger than this 0x10000 quota - to make then align you'd simply have to break them into chunks up to 0x10000, and align each separately. There's also the issue of code/stack/pagemap and other types of OS/system data which you have less control over (actually code can also be aligned, or more likely in this case - shared) - I'm assuming this has negligible impact on thrashing.

Again - this attempts to answer without knowing what system you work with, what you need to achieve, or even what is the context of the course. With more context we can probably focus this to a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I didn't know how cache is organized - I mean, at all. Indeed, if different address ranges are stored in different sets, that's not such a hard problem. The course was about parallel computations, so clearly - no hardware/os redesign is supposed. So, I guess, this is what I was expected to answer. Again, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @InnotKauker, awesome. I suggest reading a bit further about caches, always useful. In a nutshell, the caches are organized in sets so that consecutive lines would map to consecutive sets. Since this would cause collisions after you've wrapped around, you have multiple ways per set, and the lines mapping to that set would compete over them using usage-recency or frequency schemes (LRU flavors are most common). An address range therefore, would map to a range of sets, so if the process restricts itself to these sets alone, it would only compete against itself.

Answer (score 1):

How large is a way in the cache?

For example, if you have a cache where each way is 128KiB in size, you partition your memory in such a way that for each address modulo 128KiB, process A uses the 0-64KiB region, and process B uses the lower 64KiB-128KiB region. (This assumes private L1-per-core).

If your physical page size is 4KiB (and your CPU uses physical addresses for caching, not virtual - which does occur on some CPUs), you can make this much nicer. Let's say you're mapping the same amount of memory into virtual address space for each core - 16KiB. Pages 0, 2, 4, 6 go to process A's memory map, and pages 1, 3, 5, 7 go to process B's memory map. As long as you only address memory in that carefully laid out region, the caches should never fight. Of course, you've effectively halved the size of your cache-ways by doing so, but you have multiple ways...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to utilize a lock in regards to multi-thread programming. It's hard to provide an example due to not knowing your specific situation.

When one process has access, lock all other processes out until the 'accessing' process is finished with the resource.

Comment: The resource is the entire memory. I guess, locking one of the processes while the other one is working won't improve the performance, which is the main case here. Sorry if that's unclear from the question, I'll extend it...

Comment: @innot-kauker If you're looking to improve performance and there is only one memory resource, then I would think you'd want to utilize concurrency in your program.